# Share socket.io instance across pages

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, dart-pub

using this socket.io package https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client

```
  socket.onConnect((_) {
    print('connect');
    socket.emit('msg', 'test');
  });
```

I was trying to access socket variable to emit event in different page using [scoped_model](https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model) or [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) , but not working

is this correct way ?

Please Help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use some state managers like: BLOC, RIVERPOD, Provider and when the the socket emit something something you update the state or notify to listeners depending of the state manager